# ¿Cómo puedo cambiar dinámicamente la propiedad r para poder imprimir varios elementos en html?

Tags: javascript, html, frontend

```javascript
let v = 1;
let r = `nombre${v}`
console.log(r)
window.r.innerHTML  = data[0].name;
```

Quiero que `r` sea una variable *dinámica* para así poder con un `for` insertar de forma dinámica varias etiquetas que traigo en mi `array`.

Comment: por que no creas mejor un arreglo?

Comment: los datos ya los tengo en un arreglo... el tema es que no encuentro una forma para imprimirlo en una etiqueta p